# How to Compare the Data in two different Databases (Oracle and DB2)

Tags: database, oracle

We are migrating the Datawarehouse Database from Oracle to DB2 . So, now onwards Our ETL tool generates and loads the data into DB2. Here,We want to make sure the data is loaded properly into DB2 after the ETL Jobs got migrated to DB2 from Oracle. In short, How to verify the data between the two tables(one from Oracle and one from DB2) loaded by using the same job is same?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it was always a manual process. 
You write SQL to count records, verify other objects in the database.

I would assume you can export tables to a file and compare the files.
Oracle has some validation tools/products (I am not familiar with).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in testing strategy. You should build before migration.
Some case i used when migrate DWH:  Count record, sum (money_field), sum(revenue), order get top